# Disable Closure Compiler style rules

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have an old codebase that uses Closure Compiler to minify the files. We're trying to slowly modernize and optimize this codebase, so we added a job in CI that just outputs any warnings / errors.

Some of these warnings are not relevant to us, and we'd like to ignore them.

Is there a way to disable warnings via the CLI, instead of on a per file basis?

Specifically, the JSC_STRING_CONCATENATION warning. We will introduce a template language at some point which will remove the need for multiline strings in our application.

```
05:08:28  WARNING - [JSC_STRING_CONTINUATION] String continuations are not recommended. See https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-strings-no-line-continuations
05:08:28   887|                 dataid: \'' + o.dataid + '\', \
```

Comment: *"We will introduce a template language at some point which will remove the need for multiline strings in our application."* You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) right now, without introducing any further dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I haven't used CC in a decade.

Looking through the `--help`, I found the promising `--jscomp_off` option, but it didn't like `JSC_STRING_CONCATENATION` as a value.

The sledgehammer `--warning_level QUIET` worked to suppress that warning. Of course, it will also suppress others.